# Why does Opencv work with my webcam but nnot with my kinect v2?

Tags: python, opencv, kinect-v2

I am using A kinect V2 instead of a webcam for a opencv project and wanted to test some code using it. I used the laptop webcam and it worked perfectly. But with the kinect it turns on and then crashes the program and gives a error message.

This is the snippet of code.

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if not (cap.isOpened()):
    print("Could not open video device")

while(True):    
   
    ret, frame = cap.read()    
    

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
 
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):    
        break
    
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The error I got was this:-

```
[ WARN:1] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (1022) CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147024809
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\haze\Documents\GitHub\Haz3-jolt\handtrackingmodule.py", line 21, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4-dev) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

[ WARN:1] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

Comment: Kinect is an RGBD camera. Try to compile opencv with OpenNI which supports depth cameras.

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/hand-tracking-not-working-with-kinect-v2/6039